# Install an older version of a package on Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

How can I install older versions of a package on Atom Editor? In this case, I'm trying to install an older version of `Remote-FTP`, and there are older versions of the package [here](https://github.com/icetee/remote-ftp/releases), but no way to specify which version to choose when you install it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

From the Atom docs on [Packages](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/):

> You can also install packages by using the `apm install` command:
>
> - `apm install <package_name>` to install the latest version.
> - `apm install <package_name>@<package_version>` to install a specific version.
>
> For example `apm install emmet@0.1.5` installs the `0.1.5` release of the [Emmet](https://github.com/atom/emmet) package.